# Getting name spaces out of XML from simplexml_load_file in php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse this YouTube XML using simplexml_load_file in php.

The XML feed can be found here:
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=PL1mm1FfX5EHRjGyoBpEXBRIGAmCNt8pBT

Below in php I am trying to iterate through the media groups nested inside each entry node.

```
<?php

    $xmlFeed=simplexml_load_file('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=PL1mm1FfX5EHRjGyoBpEXBRIGAmCNt8pBT')
    or die("Cannot load YouTube video feed, please try again later.");

    foreach ($xmlFeed->entry->children('media', true)->group as $video) {

        echo $video->title;
        echo $video->description;
        echo $video->thumbnail->getNameSpaces(true);

    }
?>
```

Title and description print just fine. But I'm trying  to get at the thumbnail URL found in this namespace:

```
<media:thumbnail url="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/HEYQXVGnwXc/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
```

I've tried all 3 of the following:

```
echo $video->thumbnail->getNameSpaces(true);
echo $video->thumbnail->getNameSpaces(true)['url'];
echo $video->thumbnail->getNameSpaces(true)->url;
```

None return the url. The first returns Array and the last two are blank. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things: first, you have to use the [attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) function since there is no child of thumbnail. Secondly, you don't need to declare `getNameSpaces(true)` since the namespace prefix `media` is done in the `for` loop. Finally, you do not iterate across all `media:group`. Right now, you will return only the first set of xml values, not both from each `<entry>` node. Therefore, you need to add an outer loop -one that iterates across the frequency of `<entry>` nodes.

```
$attr = 'url';

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($xmlFeed->entry); $i++) {
    foreach ($xmlFeed->entry[$i]->children('media', true)->group as $video) {
        echo $video->title."\n";
        echo $video->description."\n";
        echo $video->thumbnail->attributes()->$attr."\n";    
    }   
}
```

**XPATH**  Alternative

Even further, you could have handled your needs in [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) by simply registering the media namespace and querying to exact locations, iterating of course across each set:

```
$xmlFeed->registerXPathNamespace('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');    

// ARRAYS TO HOLD XML VALUES
$videos = $xmlFeed->xpath('//media:group');
$title = $xmlFeed->xpath('//media:group/media:title');
$description = $xmlFeed->xpath('//media:group/media:description');
$url = $xmlFeed->xpath('//media:group/media:thumbnail/@url');

// ITERATING THROUGH EACH ARRAY
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($videos); $i++) {
    echo $title[$i]."\n";
    echo $description[$i]."\n";
    echo $url[$i]."\n";        
}
```

Comment: Got this solved a bit ago on my own but this is a great answer and I got to learn about Xpath. Thanks!